# hwo to display javascript within html quotes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble displaying javascript in html markup when it is contained within quotes

In the code below

`<title>{ page.seo.title }</title>`

works fine

but

```
<meta name="description" content="{ page.seo.metaDesc }" />
```

is rendered as you see it

How can I make page.seo.metaDesc display properly when the output needs quotes around it?

```
   export default function Page( {page} ) {


  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <title>{ page.seo.title }</title>
          <meta name="description" content="{ page.seo.metaDesc }" />
        </Head>
       <Header />
        <Container>
          <h1>{ page.title }</h1>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page.content }} />

          
        </Container>
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the quotation marks write it like this

```
<meta name="description" content={ page.seo.metaDesc } />
```

or use the other way

```
<meta name="description" content=`"${page.seo.metaDesc }"` />
```